# Why does testing a class method first cause other unit tests that should raise an error to fail?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm running some unit tests from the command line  `python -m unittest`.

Because of the naming of my unit tests, a unit test that is testing a class method is run first.

This will then cause other tests to fail for no reason at all. The tests that fail are all meant to raise an error, but they all fail claiming the error was never raised. When these tests are debugged in the IDE, the error is raised correctly. Also, when these tests are run individually, they pass.

When I remove the functions that test the class methods from the tests entirely. All tests pass without issue on the command line.

Can anyone offer an explanation of why this happens and what I can do to fix this? A MWE is provided below with the test output:

**Code**

```
import unittest

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_val = None

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dict_):
        cls.my_val = dict_['my_val']

    @property
    def my_val(self):
        return self._my_val

    @my_val.setter
    def my_val(self, value):
        if value == 5:
            raise ValueError
        self._my_val = value


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_classmethod(self):
        MyClass.from_dict({
            'my_val': 1
        })

    def test_my_val_raise_error(self):
        m = MyClass()
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            m.my_val = 5
            
    def test_my_val_no_error(self):
        m = MyClass()
        m.my_val = 4
        self.assertEqual(m.my_val, 4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Output**

```
"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch.py
..F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_my_val_raise_error (__main__.Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2020.3\scratches\scratch.py", line 31, in test_my_val_raise_error
    m.my_val = 5
AssertionError: ValueError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It shouldn't matter what order your tests are run in - this suggests you're failing to clear up state changes correctly. Shouldn't that class method create a new instance, though, rather than changing the state of the class itself?

Comment: I think creating a new instance causes the same problem. I'll go and check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that your class has a property named `my_val`.
But your `from_dict` class method **overrides** it and `my_val` becomes ordinary attribute (not property anymore).

This is demonstrated in the code below.

Properties can be tricky, you are welcome to read this blog I've written on this subject [here](https://medium.com/@chnlior/trespassing-the-python-property-and-staying-alive-part-1-dfe2a10178a4).

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_val = None

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dict_):
        cls.my_val = dict_['my_val']

    @property
    def my_val(self):
        return self._my_val

    @my_val.setter
    def my_val(self, value):
        if value == 5:
            raise ValueError
        self._my_val = value
        

# before override
print(MyClass.my_val) # --> <property object at 0x7f9725423950>

# override
MyClass.from_dict({'my_val': 1})

# after override
print(MyClass.my_val) # --> 1
print(type(MyClass.my_val))  # --> <class 'int'>
```

Comment: To follow up on that, the proper way of initializing your classmethod would be as followed.  Creating a temporary class instance (`myclass = cls()`), followed by the preferred assignment (`myclass.my_val = dict_['my_val']`) and  lastly returning the class instance (`return myclass`).

Comment: Yeah I figured that out when I saw in the structure window in PyCharm my class had some extra fields. I've changed the class method and everything works great now. :-)